# Replace exclamation mark with regex mutliple times

Tags: regex, erlang

I need to replace all exclamation marks in a sentence and I can do it for the first exclamation mark but I don't understand how to make it repeat for all the words/spaces in a random string without looping.

```
Sentence = "! word! hello cat! you are !! the one"
regex:replace(Sentence, "!", "" );
```

This returns " word! hello cat! you are !! the one". 
So is this possible without looping?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: There should be a "global" replace operator for whatever language you are using. In Perl, it would look like `s/!//g` (the `g` at the end says to replace all matches).

Comment: HI , I am using Erlang. I will look up the global replace character.Thanks!

Comment: Jonah, problem solved. Erlang lets you add global as an option an now it works. So re:replace("! word! hello cat! you are !! the one", "!", "", [global, {return, list}, unicode]). Returns " word hello cat you are  the one" . Thanks.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, if you solve your own problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Here's a formal answer (moving it out from the comments).*

Simply use the **global** modifier in the regular expression replace routine:

```
Sentence = "! word! hello cat! you are !! the one"
re:replace(Sentence, "!", "", [global, {return, list}, unicode])
```